I was writing a filter for api, I came across this error
I was writing a filter for my API and used the HttpServletRequest class. This class was imported from Jakarta, but when the program is run, it gives me this error:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-04-10T14:55:50.803+03:30 ERROR 10968 --- [onlineshop] [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1211) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:517) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClass(ResolvableType.java:1093) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.plugin.core.config.PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.getTargetType(PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:101) ~[spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.plugin.core.config.PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:71) ~[spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:86) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:376) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:375) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:428) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at dehghan.dani.onlineshop.OnlineshopApplicationKt.main(OnlineshopApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
    ... 37 common frames omitted


build.gradle
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.23"
}

group = "dehghan.dani"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("com.github.xiaoymin:knife4j-spring-boot-starter:3.0.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0")
    implementation("jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:5.0.0")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


I assume you're using jakarta, but your code still refers to javax: ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

My problem is exactly here, the whole project is using jakarta, so why is it saying javax HttpServletRequest Not found?

Because you are still trying to import the HttpServletRequest from javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest. You have to check your imports. Also, maybe you are using incomplatible artifacts which rely on javax, then you have to update these artifacts as well.

I checked that all the HttpServletRequests that I used were imported from Jakarta, and when I went to their classes, they did not depend on javax.

Then you haven't checked well enough, since the error explicitly explains that your code still relies on javax. Again, either your code or a 3rd party package wants to access the javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest. If it's not your code, make sure you're using compatible artifacts.

Generally this is due to trying to outsmart the Spring Boot dependency management and just slapping in some dependencies in your pom/gradle file. MOstly those are incompatible leading to these kinds of errors. Add your pom/build file to the question.

How can I edit my question to add to it?
